# How do I prove the multiplicativity of separable degree in general?

Tags: field-theory

Let $K/E/F$ be a tower of algebraic extensions. How do I prove that $[K:E]_s[E:F]_s = [K:F]_s$? This is done in all the books I searched for finite extensions (when it follows trivially from a counting argument).

The corresponding article at stacks project suggests taking $\sup$ in $[K':E']_s[E':F]_s = [K':F]_s$ over $K'/F$ finite, $E' := E \cap K'$, but it is far from obvious that this yields the first relation.

I would appreciate a reference for this; I need it in a proof that all extensions $\mathbb{F}_p \to K$ are separable in the general sense.

**Edit:** Of course, since the counting argument remains valid in the infinite case, it is enough to check that, for any (infinite) algebraic extension $E/F$, $[E : F]_s = |\mathrm{Hom}(E, \overline{F})|$, where $\overline{F}$ is some algebraic closure of $F$ and the morphisms extend some given morphism $F \to \overline{F}$.

Comment: A field $k$ is perfect if and only if $k$ has characteristic 0 or $k$ has characteristic $p$ and $k=k^p$. Does that help with your finite field extensions?

Comment: The stacks project is probably not an ideal reference for facts at this level. I'd suggest looking in your favorite algebra book (mine is Lang's Algebra, but any book with a decent bit Galois theory will do). The same proof for finite extensions should work just fine for infinite ones.

Comment: @Luis: Unfortunately, my point is that the extensions are not necessarily finite.@Frankel: Thanks for help, a second look in Lang's book made me realize that I should use the other definition (see the part after "Edit").